# how to fix error lkotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property adapters has not been initialized in my code?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

does not set adapter and work it in Kotlin

I take data from retrofit and i test it ,it work.
but when pass array list to adapter,it cant set list
and have error:

kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property adapters has not been initialized

myadapter:

```
class RecyclerSaleAdapter(var sale_list: ArrayList<sale_agahi>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerSaleAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_sale_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return  sale_list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.cost_view.text=sale_list[position].cost.toString()
        holder.area.text=sale_list[position].area
        holder.info_view.text=sale_list[position].info
        holder.metr_view.text=sale_list[position].metr.toString()

    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val ImageView=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_sale_view)
        val cost_view=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cost_text_rec_view)
        val area=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.area_text_rec_view)
        val info_view=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.info_text_rec_view)
        val metr_view=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.metr_text_rec_view)
        val btn_rec_item=itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_item_rec)
    }
}
```

myactivity on create:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        //var intent=Intent(this,Profile::class.java)
        var us= User_info()
        us.name=intent.getStringExtra("username")
        us.image_url=intent.getStringExtra("image")
        user= User_info()
        this.user =us
        get_sales_list()
        var rec=findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rec_sale)
        rec.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        rec.adapter=adapters





        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }
```

and get data fun:

```
fun get_sales_list()
    {
        var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://sobosha.ir/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val services=retrofit.create(Apiservices::class.java)
        val call =services.sale_agahi(user.name.toString())
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<sales_list> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<sales_list>, response: retrofit2.Response<sales_list>) {
                var temp:sales_list= response.body()!!
                arr_sale= temp
                Log.d("arr_sale",arr_sale.list[0].phone.toString())
                adapters=RecyclerSaleAdapter(arr_sale.list)

            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<sales_list>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,t.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }
        })
    }
```

I have an error on rec.adapter=adapters

Answer (score 0):

You only set `adapters` in the line

```
adapters=RecyclerSaleAdapter(arr_sale.list)
```

when Retrofit receives a response. The lines

```
var rec=findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rec_sale)
rec.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
rec.adapter=adapters
```

are executed after `get_sales_list` returns but the request is still likely enqueued or sent and the response is not received yet, so `adapters` isn't initialized.

One workaround would be to pass `rec` to `get_sales_list` and make it set `rec.adapter` instead of `adapters`. I'd prefer to e.g. make `get_sales_list` return `Future<sales_list>` or to make it `suspend` and return `sales_list`, but these would be more work.